# UIViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not working properly

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5, autorotate

Alright, I am not entirely sure if I will explain this sufficiently, but here it goes.

In my application I have multiple viewControllers, that are added and removed to display different views, so on and so forth. Some of these controllers, I want to allow to rotate while other I only want in say portrait mode.

However, when I go and change the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to return YES for a desired orientation, or even just always return YES, nothing happens when I rotate the device in some of the views.

The first view that I add to the application will rotate properly and does what I want it to do, but any subsequent view that I add to the window, just does not want to rotate as desired.

I set my parentview (main `UIWindow`), to `autoresizeSubViews`, and still nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` doesn't work well if you are using `[someView addSubview]`.

How are you adding additional view controllers?

Comment: that is how I am adding my views. Should I be doing it differently. I usually do something like [someView addSubiew:[someViewController view]]

Comment: as a advise , u can hide the particular controller in landscape mode..by setting its setHidden to YES ,by detecting the device orientation in which u want to hide..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem with this was simply how I was implementing my transitions and adding new views to the screen. Before I was just taking a viewcontroller viewcontroller, and adding it as a subview to the main view, so the only thing that could control the rotation was that main viewcontroller. I did not know about the [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller] thing existed. So yeah, that is what I use now and it does exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The view, you want to allow rotation, you need implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` with `return YES;` for every view! That should work, however, if you don't want to allow landscape mode, then can `return NO;` for landscape mode. (Default mode is portrait).